# Angular binding

Tags: angular6

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

У меня есть компонент "каталог" с товарами (ProductItemComponent), и есть корзина(CartComponent). Данные в каталог загружаются сервисом (обычный массив, хардкод). Когда жму "добавить в корзину" - товар добавляется, но в корзине его видно только после перезагрузки. Как сделать автоматическое отображение добавленого товара в козине по клику на кнопку? То есть, как сделать binding между разными компонентами?

(Если это важно - товары сохраняю в LocalStorage)

Answer (score 0):

```
в  контроллере: 
public items:mytype[]=[];

addItem(myType item){
items.push(item);
}

в html:
<div *ngFor="let i of items">
<div >i</div>
</div>
```

ну примерно будет выглядеть так, и там где список товаров добавить `<button (click)="addItem(товар)"></button>`

Comment: а как вы бы написали?

Comment: что именно неправильно?